# Check if an object array value is null

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, object

How can I check if an Object Array value is null?
In this case, I want to check if the *price* value is null

for example

```
available_cars:{
cars:[
{name:"BMW", price:2000000}
{name:"Volkswagen", price:1500000}
{name:"Audi", price:null}
]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.some` and compare it to `null`:

```js
available_cars = {
  cars: [{
    name: "BMW",
    price: 2000000
  }, {
    name: "Volkswagen",
    price: 1500000
  }, {
    name: "Audi",
    price: null
  }]
}

const res = available_cars.cars.some(e => e.price === null)
console.log(res)
```

Comment: I don't want to filter out the ones that have a null value. I want to check if any of them has a null value for price.

Answer (score 0):

```
available_cars = {
  cars: [{
    name: "BMW",
    price: 2000000
  }, {
    name: "Volkswagen",
    price: 1500000
  }, {
    name: "Audi",
    price: null
  }]
}

const res = available_cars.cars.forEach(car => {

   if(!car.price){
// handle case
    }

});
console.log(res)
```